# Accordion with vertical divisions in the title

Tags: go, fyne

I'm looking for a way of creating accordion entries with formatted vertical divisions.
Think a table that when a row is clicked it expands, as an accordion does, to show the content related to the row.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you’d need to make a custom widget, but that’s ok as Fyne is designed to make that possible :).
https://developer.fyne.io/extend/custom-widget